# Nagios is alerting CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 30 seconds but it is running

Tags: debian, nagios

I have nagios on my server which is alerting me

```
CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 30 seconds.
```

But my service is running:

```
● nagios-nrpe-server.service - Nagios Remote Plugin Executor
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nagios-nrpe-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-04-18 00:31:56 CEST; 6min ago
     Docs: http://www.nagios.org/documentation
  Process: 4841 ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /var/run/nagios/nrpe.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4845 (nrpe)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nagios-nrpe-server.service
           ├─4845 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -f
           ├─6346 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -f
           ├─6347 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -f
           ├─6348 sh -c /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -e -w 5% -W 3% -c 2% -K 2% -X tmpfs
           └─6349 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -e -w 5% -W 3% -c 2% -K 2% -X tmpfs
```

I tryed to kill it, restart it, restart nagios server which is processing all alerts, but nothing worked. It started from nothing, and don't know there is the catch since all other server which are nagios are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout is coming from the client plugin `check_nrpe`, terminating the connection after 30 seconds.

I don't think there is a proper timeout in the NRPE servers, but most plugins should implement timeout behavior.

Comment: we have timeout setup for 30seconds, should I incrase it in this case?

Comment: @Delirium you should rather find out why check_disk hangs, probably a broken NFS share or other network mount

Comment: It was hetwork issue, when my network disk disconected this was caused